# Floating a list of <a> anchor elements within a div

Tags: html, css

So, I've been trying to work on a website from scratch, in a simple, blocky format, where the navigation is at the top of the page, as an unordered list full of `<a>` elements, all into list tags, also within a `<nav>` tag, as such;

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.bdy {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #d2d2d2;
  height: 85%;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
nav.navbar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 15%;
  width: 100%;
}
nav ul {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #326ada;
  width: 97.9%;
}
nav.navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-top: 10%;
}
nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="first">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Assignments</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="bdy">
  <p>content</p>
</div>
```

What I want to do is have it where the unordered list has its elements always at the bottom of the Navigation area (Blue), about 10px from the bottom, and using margins with percentages doesn't seem to work very well.

Is there any way that I could float the list, without disturbing order, downwards?

Comment: please edit your css code into legible code blocks

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is avoid the use of the `%` margin and instead make the text inside each `a` align to the bottom of the lists, try this:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.bdy {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #d2d2d2;
  height: 85%;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
nav.navbar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}
nav ul {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #326ada;
  width: 97.9%;
}
nav.navbar li {
  float: left;
  height:100%;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
nav li:before {
  content:"";
  height:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="first">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Assignments</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="bdy">
  <p>content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of unnecessary stuff in your CSS code. Have a look at my snippet and the settings in there, I suppose that's what you want.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.bdy {
  min-height: 85%;
  background-color: #d2d2d2;
}

nav.navbar {
  position: relative;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: red;
}

nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #326ada;
  padding: 5px 0 2px 0;
}

nav.navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="first">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Assignments</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="bdy">
  <p>content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I understand it's a bit unnecessary, and I should've specified a bit more. I pulled directly from the project itself, and at the time, I had removed an `<img>` tag that I had forgotten in the CSS portion. Additionally, the red background for the `<nav>` element was actually a visual aid, so I could test whether the unordered list, and its background would fill the space the red had. I am trying to get the blue part of the navigation to be 150 - 200px tall, with the `<a>` list elements at the bottom left of it. Sorry for the confusion.